# FlatList load on end triggers... React Native

Tags: react-native

I've tried onEndReacehdthreshold from 0 to 1 but still it spam trigers,
and I've tried 
`onEndReached={()=>{this.onEndReached()}`
  it only trigers one time

```
onEndReached(){
     this.GetData()
}


 render(){
  return(
  <View>
     <ScrollView ...>
      <FlatList ....
            ....
               onEndReached={ this.onEndReached() }
               onEndReachedThreshold={0}
        />
      </ScrollView>
     </View>

)}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use it with `EndReached`, the height is not found in the `Flatlist`.
Do not use the `Flatlist` in `ScrollView`.

Comment: @Isme If my answer was helpful, could you check my 'V' mark check and arrow?

Comment: but i need scroll view to put other component at top so when i scroll down it hides. is there other way to achieve?